# How to setup an admin account for Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm running Clickhouse in a docker container on a Windows host. I tried to create an account towards making it an admin account. It looks like the **default** user does not have permission to create other accounts. How can I get around this error and create an admin account?

```
docker-compose exec -T dash-clickhouse clickhouse-client --query="CREATE USER 'foo' IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY 'bar'"
```

gave the error

```
Received exception from server (version 20.7.2):
Code: 497. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: default: Not enough privileges. To execute this query it's necessary to have the grant CREATE USER ON *.*.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix it need to enable [`access_management`](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings-users/#access_management-user-setting)-setting in the `users.xml` file:

```sh
#  execute an interactive bash shell on the container
docker-compose exec {container_name} bash
# docker exec -it {container_name} bash

# install preferable text editor (i prefer using 'nano')
apt-get update
apt-get install nano

# open file users.xml in the editor
nano /etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml
```

Uncomment the `access_management`-setting for the `default` user and save changes:

```xml
..
<!-- User can create other users and grant rights to them. -->
<!-- <access_management>1</access_management> -->
..
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!! It will be nice to have it set by .env file. Few steps below that I added to create admin user on my dev machine:

CREATE USER 'foo' IDENTIFIED WITH plaintext_password BY 'bar'
SET allow_introspection_functions=1
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'foo' WITH GRANT OPTION

Answer (score 5):

```
mkdir -p  ~/Documents/docker/click/etc/conf.d

cat ~/Documents/docker/click/etc/conf.d/zxylalalhuayk.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
    <users>
        <default>
     <access_management>1</access_management>
        </default>
    </users>
</yandex>


docker run -d --name test  -v ~/Documents/docker/click/etc/conf.d/:/etc/clickhouse-server/conf.d --ulimit nofile=262144:262144  -p 8123:8123 yandex/clickhouse-server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running clickhouse-server via the image from docker hub, the easiest way would be to pass in the login via environment variables

> ## How to create default database and user on starting
>
> Sometimes you may want to create a user (user named default is used by default) and database on a container start. You can do it using environment variables `CLICKHOUSE_DB`, `CLICKHOUSE_USER`, `CLICKHOUSE_DEFAULT_ACCESS_MANAGEMENT` and `CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD`:

```
docker run --rm -e CLICKHOUSE_DB=my_database -e CLICKHOUSE_USER=username -e CLICKHOUSE_DEFAULT_ACCESS_MANAGEMENT=1 -e CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=password -p 9000:9000/tcp clickhouse/clickhouse-server
```

If you leave these out, clickhouse gives you a `default` user which can do everything... except SQL-driven access control and account management. That's what the `CLICKHOUSE_DEFAULT_ACCESS_MANAGEMENT=1` allows.

https://hub.docker.com/r/clickhouse/clickhouse-server/